# Use routing logic when dispatching resources with simmer package (or an alternative)

Tags: r, simulation, event-simulation

Is there a way to use a (customized) routing engine together with the `simmer` package for discrete-event simulation? (or an alternative package)

---

Context: I'm running dicrete-event simulations (DES) with R. Till now all my simulations are built without using one of the R packages designed for DES. Since my code gets bigger and bigger (and performance worse) I'm thinking about switching to one of the R packages designed for DES.

For some portions of my code I see how I could switch it to `simmer`. But till now I couldn't figure out how to use a routing-logic together with resource dispatching.

---

Example: The following minimal example shows what kind of functionality I need (and couldn't figure out how to build with simmer).

Generate some data, `events` (jobs) and `resources`

```
set.seed(1)

events <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3L,
  t = sort(trunc(rexp(3) * 100)),
  position = runif(3),
  resource = NA,
  worktime = NA
)

resources <- data.frame(
  id = 1:2L,
  position = c(0.2, 0.8),
  t_free = 0
)
```

Simplified version of a routing logic: calculate the route based on position of  `event` and `resources`. (For the example just points on a 1-D space between 0 and 1, in the real example a customized version of `OSRM` algorithm together with historical data..)

```
waytime <- function(events, resources, i) {
  trunc(abs(events$position[i] - resources$position[resources$id == events$resource[i]]) * 100)
}
```

Two versions of the simulation. `sim` just takes the first available resource with no thinking about the `waytime`. `sim_nearest` calculates `waytimes` for all free resources and dispatches to the closest one. `sim_nearest` is what I want in my real examples and don't know how to build using `simmer`.

```
sim <- function(events, resources) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(events)) {
    # Default dispatching: Use the first free vehicle
    events$resource[i] <- resources$id[resources$t_free <= events$t[i]][1]
    # Simulate event
    events$worktime[i] <- waytime(events, resources, i)
    resources$t_free[events$resource[i]] <- events$t[i] + events$worktime[i]
  }
  return(list(events = events, resources = resources))
}

sim_use_nearest <- function(events, resources) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(events)) {
    # Dispatching by position: Use the nearest free resource
    ids_free <- resources$id[resources$t_free <= events$t[i]]
    events$resource[i] <- resources$id[which.min(abs(resources$position[ids_free] - events$position[i]))]
    # Simulate event
    events$worktime[i] <- waytime(events, resources, i)
    resources$t_free[events$resource[i]] <- events$t[i] + events$worktime[i]
  }
  return(list(events = events, resources = resources))
}
```

Simulate the two alternatives:

```
res <- sim(events, resources)
res_use_nearest <- sim_use_nearest(events, resources)
```

See the differences:

```
res$events
# id   t  position resource worktime
#  1  14 0.9082078        1       70
#  2  75 0.2016819        2       59
#  3 118 0.8983897        1       69
res$resources
# id position t_free
#  1      0.2    187
#  2      0.8    134
res_use_nearest$events
# id   t  position resource worktime
#  1  14 0.9082078        2       10
#  2  75 0.2016819        1        0
#  3 118 0.8983897        2        9
res_use_nearest$resources
# id position t_free
#  1      0.2     75
#  2      0.8    127
```

Is it possible to generate the same results with simmer (or another R DES package)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samy's approach is fine, but I would take a slightly different one (note that this isn't tested, because I didn't write the necessary `routing_logic` function):

```
library(simmer)

env <- simmer()

t <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("available_resources") %>%
  set_attribute(c("res_id", "delay"), routing_logic) %>%
  select(function() paste0("res_", get_attribute(env, "res_id"))) %>%
  seize_selected() %>%
  timeout_from_attribute("delay") %>%
  release_selected() %>%
  release("available_resources")
```

Note that `"available_resources"` (which must be a resource with a capacity equal to the number of resources you have) is like a token. Once seized, it means that there's some resource available. Otherwise, events just sit there and wait.

`routing_logic()` must be a function that selects a `"res_id"` based on some policy (e.g., first available or nearest), computes the delay and returns both values, which are stored as attributes. In that function, you may use `get_capacity()` to know the status of each resource without having to set `t_free`. You may also retrieve the `position` attribute for that event, which will be set automatically as follows:

```
set.seed(1)

events <- data.frame(
  t = sort(trunc(rexp(3) * 100)),
  position = runif(3)
)

resources <- data.frame(
  id = 1:2L,
  position = c(0.2, 0.8)
)

env %>% 
  add_dataframe("event_", t, events, mon=2, col_time="t", time="absolute") %>%
  add_resource("available_resources", capacity=nrow(resources))

for (id in resources$id) env %>%
  add_resource(paste0("res_", id), capacity=1, queue_size=0)
```

As you can see, I have directly connected the `events` data frame to the trajectory (you don't need the `resource` and `worktime` anymore; the former will be stored as the `res_id` attribute, and the latter will be automatically monitored by `simmer` and retrieved with `get_mon_arrivals()`). We specify that `t` is the time column, and the other one, `position` will be added to each event as an attribute, as I said before.

With this setup, you just need to redefine `routing_logic()` to achieve different policies and different results.

Answer (score 3):

Following you'll find a possible solution for your minimal example with the `simmer` package.

First we chose the alternative to simulate which is later used in `set_attribute`:

```
sim_first_available <- T
sim_use_nearest <- F
```

Generate the `events` and `resources` data as before.

```
set.seed(1)

events <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3L,
  t = sort(trunc(rexp(3) * 100)),
  position = runif(3),
  resource = NA,
  worktime = NA
)

resources <- data.frame(
  id = 1:2L,
  position = c(0.2, 0.8),
  t_free = 0
)
```

Start `simmer` with the trajectory `sim`.

```
library(simmer)

sim <- trajectory() %>%
```

Then set `t_free` as a global attribute. At the first arrival (t = 14) you can use `t_free` from the resource data to initialize. At later arrivals use `get_global` to get the current `t_free` of the specific resource.

```
  set_global(paste0("t_free_res_", resources$id), function() {
    if (now(env) == 14) {return(resources$t_free) # Initialize parameters when first event arrives
    } else {
      get_global(env, paste0("t_free_res_", resources$id))
    }}) %>%
```

Now define the attributes for this event:

Based on the current simulation time choose the `event_position` from the data frame `events`.

```
  set_attribute(c("event_position","my_resource", "timeout"), function() {
    t <- now(env)
    event_position <- events$position[events$t == t]
```

`my_resource` is chosen acc. to the alternative you want to simulate.

```
    t_free <- get_global(env, paste0("t_free_res_", resources$id))
    if (sim_first_available & !sim_use_nearest) {
      my_resource <- resources$id[t_free <= now(env)][1]
    } else if (!sim_first_available & sim_use_nearest){
      ids_free <- resources$id[t_free <= now(env)]
      my_resource <- resources$id[which.min(abs(resources$position[ids_free] - event_position))]
    }
```

Based on the `resource_pos` calculate the `timeout` for that resource and return the attributes:

```
resource_pos <- resources$position[resources$id == my_resource]
        timeout <- trunc(abs(event_position - resource_pos)*100)

        return(c(event_position, my_resource, timeout))
      }) %>%
```

Select the defined resource and seize it:

```
  select(resources = function() paste0("res_", get_attribute(env, "my_resource"))) %>%
  seize_selected(amount = 1) %>%
```

Now overwrite `t_free` of that resource by adding the `timeout` to the current simulation time.

```
  set_global(function() {
    paste0("t_free_res_", get_attribute(env, "my_resource"))
  }, function() {
    return(now(env) + get_attribute(env, "timeout"))
  }) %>%
```

Set the calculated timeout to the resource and release it again.

```
  timeout(function() get_attribute(env, "timeout")) %>% 
  release_selected(amount = 1)
```

Finally generate the events for the trajectory `sim` at the defined time intervals in events, add the resources and run the simulation.

```
env <- simmer()  %>%
  add_generator("event_", sim, at(events$t), mon = 2) %>%
  add_resource("res_1", capacity = 1) %>%
  add_resource("res_2", capacity = 1)

env %>% run()

print(get_mon_attributes(env))
print(get_mon_arrivals(env))
print(get_mon_resources(env))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Iñaki's approch is very useful, as it uses features of the newest simmer version. Out of interest I completed his example with a routing logic and - as expected - the results are the same. Thanks for your Input Iñaki.

```
library(simmer)

env <- simmer()

t <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("available_resources") %>%
  set_attribute(c("res_id", "delay"), function() {
    # find available resources
    capacities <- numeric(nrow(resources))
    for (i in 1:length(capacities)) {
      capacities[i] <- get_server_count(env, paste0("res_", resources$id[i]))
    }
    available <- ifelse(capacities == 0, T, F)
    index_available <- which(available)
    # calculate the delay for available resources
    event_position <- get_attribute(env, "position")
    delay <- trunc(abs(event_position - resources$position[available])*100)
    # take the nearest available resource. 
    index <- index_available[which.min(delay)]
    return(c(index,min(delay)))
  }) %>%
  select(function() paste0("res_", get_attribute(env, "res_id"))) %>%
  seize_selected() %>%
  timeout_from_attribute("delay") %>%
  release_selected() %>%
  release("available_resources")
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
set.seed(1)

events <- data.frame(
  t = sort(trunc(rexp(3) * 100)),
  position = runif(3)
)

resources <- data.frame(
  id = 1:2L,
  position = c(0.2, 0.8)
)

env %>% 
  add_dataframe("event_", t, events, mon=2, col_time="t", time="absolute") %>%
  add_resource("available_resources", capacity=nrow(resources))
for (id in resources$id) env %>%
  add_resource(paste0("res_", id), capacity=1, queue_size=0)

env %>% run()
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
library(simmer.plot)
print(plot(get_mon_resources(env), metric = "usage", c("available_resources", "res_1", "res_2"), items = "server", steps = TRUE))
```